# Problem returning a function with Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

i'm new to python. Trying to do some webscraping(get a url, pretty simple), my function works. But when i tried to use the function with discord.py it returns a "27%" at the end of the url.

**url is "'https://readms.net'"**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def mangareader():

    url = ""
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

    links = []
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))

    usefulmangas = []
    for i in links:
        if "/haikyuu/" in i:
            usefulmangas.append(i)
        elif "/my_hero_academia/" in i:
            usefulmangas.append(i)

    haikyuulink = url + usefulmangas[0]
    bokunoherolink = url + usefulmangas[1]

    return haikyuulink, bokunoherolink
```

## That's how i'm calling in the `discord.py`

```
import discord
from teste import mangareader

TOKEN = ''
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!manga'):
        await message.channel.send(f"{mangareader()}")



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Hey, welcome. Before anything can you give details about what you are doing in discord.py cuz only this much information is insufficient! And if you are trying to scrap manga or get latest manga chapters, manga reader is easier to scrap. Well both sites have no restrictions but go with mangareader!

Comment: Hello @ASHu2, thank you for the advice! Well, i'm trying to make a bot that returns the url from [link](readms.net) when i type !manga. The function `mangareader()` is working fine. The problem is when i run the if statement in discord.py it adds a %27  at the end in the last url like this "'https://readms.net/r/my_hero_academia/235/6040/1%27"

Comment: You can just convert the url to string like `url = "readms.net/r/my_hero_academia/235/6040/1%27"` then use `url = url[:-3]`. If it is always happening you can do this. Else I need to see your discord.py to get what the error exactly is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the url is always converted to `%27` at the end, then you can store the url in a value:

```
url = "readms.net/r/my_hero_academia/235/6040/1%27"
new_url = url[:-3]
```

then use this value.

Edit:
if you look at html encodings, you can see `%27 : ‘`. [Link](https://krypted.com/utilities/html-encoding-reference/).

Comment: I updated the code, i tried that just now and it doesn't work. It does remove the 3 last letters, but the `%27` still there. It only happens when i try to run with the discord.py. The discord.py code is now in the first post.

Comment: no i mean use this in discord.py. Else without seeing what the code is I can't help!

Comment: I discovered what it's going on. the problem was the quotes in the url. The last one in `'readms.net/r/my_hero_academia/235/6040/1'` turns to a %27 i don't know why. But now i know the problem. Thanks for the help!